# Ideal in-memory data structure for removing duplicates from approx. 100,000 integers

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to load a file that contains maybe around 100,000 integers. In the process of loading, I want to remove the duplicates and insert the rest into a database.

1. Which is the ideal data-structure in C#?
2. Would B-trees be ideal for my case, and if so, is there a B-tree implementation in C#?

(I am new to C#.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I think he meant 1L = Int64.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807. Your edit seems incorrect to me. Storing 100k integers wouldn't be a problem and I would be surprised anyone asking such question. But we never know.

Comment: @Darin `1L` is still only `1` if you interpret is as a long suffix. And you can't store `Int64.MaxValue` numbers. On the other hand it's not uncommon for Indian programmers on SO to use Lakh as unit. I'm pretty sure my edit is correct.

Comment: To the OP - in the international community, Lakh is not very common. Sticking to raw numbers is simplest.

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply use an `HashSet<T>`. It will ignore duplicates.

Note that enumerating an `HashSet<T>` returns the elements in unspecified order.

---

If you need sorting, look into `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. It's tree based, and will probably be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 1L == 1Lakh, this is not a large amount.

Just use a collection type that does not allow duplicates such as a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> The HashSet(Of T) class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.